# Goodness of fit for mixture model?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, skewness, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

I have a problem with my vector, I thought that it was a mixture of 2 skew T and I intent to use the ks.test:

```r
set.seed(1)
arg1 = c(al.stri.sT$mu[1], al.stri.sT$sigma2[1], al.stri.sT$shape[1], 
         al.stri.sT$nu)
arg2 = c(c(al.stri.sT$mu[2], al.stri.sT$sigma2[2], 
         al.stri.sT$shape[2], al.stri.sT$nu))
#y e' il mio vettore di dati
y <- rmix(n=1000, p=al.stri.sT$pii, family="Skew.t", 
          arg=list(arg1,arg2))
a.y <- smsn.mix(y,nu=3,g=2,family = "Skew.t")
```

y is may vector and now I want use the ks.test

```r
ssst <- function(x, mu, sigma2, pii,shape,nu) {
  pii[1]*pst(x,mu[1],sigma2[1],shape[1],nu) + 
    (1-pii[1])*pst(x,mu[2],sigma2[2],shape[2],nu)}
```

I create the mixture of 2 skewT above and at the end I use the test:

```r
ks.test(y, ssst, mu=a.y$mu, sigma=a.y$sigma2, 
        pii=a.y$pii, shape=a.y$shape,nu=a.y$nu)
```

my p values is smaller than my expectation, is good my work or did I do some errors ?

```r
One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

>data:  y
>D = 0.27073, p-value < 2.2e-16
>alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Comment: Since this is a simulation experiment and not a data analysis, you should include a reproducible example.

Comment: I think that this is reproducible I create all in R, i use this library:library(dgof)
library(sn)
library(mixsmsn)

Comment: I don't see what's wrong at first sight, but then I'm not entirely sure about all the arguments for the functions and whether they are correctly used. Did you try out ks.test using the original arg1 and arg2? This should surely not give a p-value <2.2e-16 unless you're doing something wrong. Also, did you have a look at the y? Maybe a histogram or density plot compared with a density plot of your original density (and the one resulting from smsn.mix) to see whether the problem is somehow with the data generation? I'm pretty sure you can nail down where the problem is by looking at such things.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the truth y is only an example, It is not important in my situation. You can imagine y as a vector of a dataset (I build y in this mode to simulate my true vector and for sharing them with you, but y is not important). I think that my model maybe is not correct, I'm not entirely sure too about all the arguments for the functions and whether they are correctly used. My scope is to do the ks test (a goodness of fit more general) to prove if the distribution is a mixture of 2 skewT or not. But for my skills a goodnes of fit of a mixture is very hard.  @Lewian

Comment: I'd still think you need to build some examples and look exactly at what happens to find out what's wrong. Your general thinking seems fine (except that a test generally cannot "prove" that its null hypothesis is true), so the problem must be somewhere in the code, something doesn't do what you think it does, and I gave you some ideas what to look at in order to find out.

Comment: @Lewian see pleese the answer belove

Answer (score 1):

[image]

@Lewian
this is the histogram for the vector above "y". In my opinion I think that I have a good adaptation for this reason the p-value above is too small.
I did another prove with this result:

```
set.seed(3)
Tprova1<-c(rst(60), rst(60,5))
hist(Tprova1, breaks = 30)
a1.Tprova<-smsn.mix(Tprova1,nu=3,g=2,family = "Skew.t")
```

I built a vector with 2 skewT (Random) and in this case the p-value doesn't reject the null hypothesis (ssst is the function that I built above):

```
ks.test(Tprova1, ssst, mu=a1.Tprova$mu, sigma=a1.Tprova$sigma2, 
        pii=a1.Tprova$pii, shape=a1.Tprova$shape,nu=a1.Tprova$nu)
```

> One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

> data:  Tprova1
> D = 0.096289, p-value = 0.2158

and it is the histogram of the frequency with the model

```
mix.hist(Tprova1,a1.Tprova)
```

[image]

So, I think that I have some problems with the goodness of fit above

Comment: What's the problem here? Everything up to and including the ks.test looks fine for the new data. So it can't be used to find the problem with the old data. You need to reproduce the problem and investigate that dataset in detail. Generally I have given you some hints what you can do to get to the bottom of this (which you haven't all tried out it seems), but it involves experimentation and you have to do it yourself.